# Problem in XML parsing using DOM

Tags: android, dom

I'm parsing an xml content from web service,it creates a problem when parsing the content with 
**Brown Men’sHockey “Grows for Movember”**,when I parse like this by using DOM parses it results **Brown Men** after the hexadecimal code,the parse is not accepting remaining characters,here the code to parse

```
NodeList items = elt.getElementsByTagName(ITEM);
            for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                Message_desc message = new Message_desc();
                Node item = items.item(i);
                NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node property = properties.item(j);
                    String name = property.getNodeName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCRIPTION)) {
                        message.setDescription(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
.....}
```

what I need to do here,please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        description = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            description[i] = new TextView(this);

            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
            NodeList dataList =      fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("description");
            Element dataElement = (Element) dataList.item(0);
            dataList = dataElement.getChildNodes();
            description[i].setText( ((Node) dataList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
```

Comment: swathi..thanks for your answer...before answer the question check the date when it's asked...